# Memory error when computing eigenvalues in python

Tags: python, numpy, graph, out-of-memory, networkx

I try to find eigenvalues of adjacency matrix of a large graph (465,017 nodes, 834,797 edges). I try to find values using NetworkX adjacency_spectrum method. When I compiling I have a memory error.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "5.py", line 19, in <module>
    w=nx.adjacency_spectrum(G)
  File "/home/aiym/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/networkx/linalg/spectrum.py", line 75, in adjacency_spectrum
    return eigvals(nx.adjacency_matrix(G,weight=weight).todense())
  File "/home/aiym/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 691, in todense
    return np.asmatrix(self.toarray(order=order, out=out))
  File "/home/aiym/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 920, in toarray
    return self.tocoo(copy=False).toarray(order=order, out=out)
  File "/home/aiym/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py", line 252, in toarray
    B = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)
  File "/home/aiym/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 1009, in _process_toarray_args
    return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)
MemoryError
```

Can you help me to fix this problem? or suggest other methods to compute eigenvalues without memory error

Comment: Do you need all of the eigenvalues?  Can you get away with just the largest?

Comment: @Joel I need all values

Comment: Not directly relevant to your question, but it would be a major surprise to me if the 400,000th eigenvalue is relevant to anything.  So you'll need to figure out a way to get numpy to find all eigenvalues of that matrix.

Comment: I would recommend adding numpy to your tags since that's where the memory error is occurring.

Comment: @Joel thanks,added. I try to implement graph Fourier transform and in order to do it i need all eigenvalues.

Comment: Your graph is too big and you need a lot of memory to be able to run your code. How much RAM do you have on your computer? I would say there are two ways: either increase your computer's memory (use a cluster) or compute the adjacency matrix as you need. Without sharing your code, how could one is able to help you